# Como tener varios modales en la misma pagina utilizando Django?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, django

Tengo una duda respecto a usar varios modales, en una sola página, ahora tengo este código elaborado:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal1" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Corespondencia</button>

         <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
               <div class="modal-content">
                     <!--Aqui entra la plantilla de registros para Correspondencia -->
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
       <!--Parte del boton de cites -->
       <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal2" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Cites</button>

           <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                 <!-- Aqui va la plantilla de citatorios -->
               </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y el script que utilizo es éste:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#modal1').modal(options) 
   $('#modal2').modal(options) 
 </script>
```

Pero no me sale nada si le cambio el nombre del modal, no me muestra nada. ¿Alguien podría decirme en dónde está el error? O si es q puse algo mal.

Comment: los modales van a ser dinamicos? o seran máximo 2?

Comment: Te falta añadir el atributo `id='modal1'` a las cajas que son modal. Por otra parte para llamar a los modales con jquery debes llamarlo así `$('#modal1')`.

Comment: ya corregir ese error pero me sale el modal, sobrepuesto, osea una plantilla, sobre otra